# Cannot get canopy height from dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I just can't work out why this reducer does not work and give me the average canopy height. The reducer output is null even though there are pixels in the area.

```
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

var filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM0_NAME', ['Brazil']);
var filteredArea = fromList.filter(filter);


var dataset = ee.Image('NASA/JPL/global_forest_canopy_height_2005').clip(filteredArea);
var forestCanopyHeight = dataset.select('1');
var forestCanopyHeightVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 30.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(forestCanopyHeight, forestCanopyHeightVis, 'Forest Canopy Height');
    
var stats = forestCanopyHeight.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: filteredArea.geometry(),
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print (stats);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be hitting some kind of upper limit in the calculations, as the area is quite large, but no error message.  You are looking for the "MAX" not the "mean" in your code.

If you change your scale to 250, it will work.

```
var stats = forestCanopyHeight.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: filteredArea.geometry(),
  scale: 250,  // change this to 250M
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
```